# Deserializing JSON-valued string

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

We are using Spring Boot to expose a REST endpoint which is called by a dumb client which delivers us the following:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2016-08-16T14:30.000Z",
    "data": "{\"amount\":1,\"product\":\"BASIC PRODUCT\"}"
}
```

We've created the following objects:

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Message.Builder.class)
public final class Message {
    private final String timestamp;
    private final Data data;

    public String getTimestamp() {...}
    public Data getData() {...}

    @JsonPOJOBuilder
    public static final class Builder {
        private String timestamp;
        private Data data;

        public Builder withTimestamp(final String timestamp) {...}
        public Builder withData(final Data data) {...}
    }
}
```

and

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Data.Builder.class)
public final class Data {
    private final String product;
    private final int amount;

    public String getProduct() {...}
    public int getAmount() {...}

    @JsonPOJOBuilder
    public static final class Builder {
        private String product;
        private int amount;

        public Builder withProduct(final String product) {...}
        public Builder withAmount(final int amount) {...}
    }
}
```

and exposed the endpoint as

```
@RequestMapping(consumes = "application/json", method = POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> receive(@RequestBody Message message) {
   /// ...
}
```

but control doesn't even reach the `receive` method and fails with `400 BAD REQUEST`. I believe this has to do with the fact that `data` is a JSON-valued string. Does Jackson provide any annotation that I can use to force the JSON-valued string to be deserialized as an instance of `Data`?

Comment: Have you tried annotating the `product` field as `type`, or adding a `type` field? Likely there's a failure on unknown/missing properties?

Comment: Sorry, I had mistyped the names. I've corrected them now. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Does the body of the `400 BAD REQUEST` response say anything useful? Is any useful exception being logged?

Comment: Since the RequestMapping has "consumes = "application/json"", check if the appropriate headers are set by the client while sending the POST request. I think in this case, the missing header can produce a HTTP 400 response from the service.

Comment: What is your `build` method in the builder?

Answer (score 0):

The key is in `public Builder withData()` method of `Message.Builder.class` to explicitly parse JSON-valued string to `Data` type. Change the method parameter to String instead of `Data` and call `ObjectMapper().readValue(JSON-valued string, Data.class)` to deserialize it into `Data`.

For example like this:

```
public Builder withData(final String jsonValue) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    Data data = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonValue, Data.class);
    this.data = data;
    return this;
}
```

For the clarity sake here you are my whole POJOs:

Message:

```
public final class Message {
    private final String timestamp;
    private final Data data;

    private Message(Builder builder){
        this.timestamp = builder.timestamp;
        this.data = builder.data;
    }

    public String getTimestamp() {...}
    public Data getData() {...}

    @JsonPOJOBuilder
    public static final class Builder {
        private String timestamp;
        private Data data;

        private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        public Builder withTimestamp(final String timestamp) {
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
            return this;
        }
        public Builder withData(final String jsonValue) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
            Data data = mapper.readValue(jsonValue, Data.class);
            this.data = data;
            return this;
        }
        public Message build() {
            return new Message(this);
        }
    } // Builder
}
```

Data:

```
public final class Data {
    private final String product;
    private final int amount;

    private Data(Builder builder){
        this.product = builder.product;
        this.amount = builder.amount;
    }

    public String getProduct() {...}
    public int getAmount() {...}

    @JsonPOJOBuilder
    public static final class Builder {
        private String product;
        private int amount;

        public Builder withProduct(final String product) {
            this.product = product;
            return this;
        }
        public Builder withAmount(final int amount) {
            this.amount = amount;
            return this;
        }
        public Data build() {
            return new Data(this);
        }
    } // Builder
}
```

Hope it helps.